# Fridge died for New Years eve. Should I replace the overload protector or the whole relay? (full details, testing inside)

Tags: electrical, wiring, refrigerator, appliances, relay

Fridge: Sears 970-681020

Combination relay: 213615005 (embraco/eecon tsd-115/127v-60hz-y)

Compressor: egz 70hlp embraco

Symptoms: Click, BRRRRR (4 seconds), Click....... no cooling

Tests: Pulled the combo relay. Tested continuity on the motor, all good. No rattle in the relay, mild smoke smell. I pulled the overload out of the relay and found a slightly burned connection: https://imgur.com/a/DnUPIAC

The relay left to right (start-run?) reads 31Ω and the thermistor appears intact

Question: I found a single combination relay of this exact model # but it costs $195 .... can i replace just the overload protection part, if so, what part #? [This looks visually identical](https://www.amazon.ca/6750C-0004R-Overload-Protector-Refrigerators-PartsBroz/dp/B07P6GWQSY). If I have to replace the whole relay, what are the chances this actually fixes the problem, i don't want to spend $200 on a part that dies in a few weeks. And are there alternative relay parts other than specifically the #213615005?

I'm able to test other stuff if needed.

(I erred on the side of too much information in case it helps any, I know people are busy after the holidays)

Edit: I'll probably buy and install [this](https://www.amazon.ca/WR07X10097-Refrigerator-Compressor-Replacement-AP4300623/dp/B09Q6DRNGC) tomorrow unless an expert tells me otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the whole circuit (relay + overload) with this:

WR07X10097 Refrigerator Compressor Relay Overload Starter for GE Refrigerator Relay and Overload Assembly Replacement Part 1265640 AP4300623 PS1766101 513604045

Before I put it in the fridge, some testing showed that my overload was the culprit. Either way, the fridge has been running 48hrs without issue so far.

For future searchers, I think matching the part to the compressor is more sensible than trying to match to the fridge.